# Python ActivePivot MDX get result as CSV

Tags: python, activepivot

Here is my code to connect AP

```
import win32com.client

conn = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
DSN = ('Provider=MSOLAP.4;Password=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Initial Catalog=Murex Cubes;Data Source=https://<host>:<port>/pivot/xmla;Location=https://<host>:<port>/pivot/xmla;')
conn.Open(DSN)

rs = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
strsql = "SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize([AsOfDate].[AsOfDate].Members) ON ROWS FROM [MICube]"
rs.Open(strsql, conn, 1, 3)
t = rs.GetRows()
conn.Close()
```

But I am getting the following error message.

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0,
>   u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 2008.', u'Either a
>   connection cannot be made to the www. server, or Analysis
>   Services is not running on the computer specified.', None, 0,
>   -2147467259), None)

Comment: What's your ActivePivot version ? Are you able to connect with Excel ?

Comment: ActivePivot version is 2017.1.2.5.1. Yes, it is connecting through Excel from the production server. This connection I am trying from my desktop client machine. I have the necessary permission for my user id.

Comment: Hi usually ActivePivot version is X.Y.Z, yours either is 4.y.z or 5.y.z, you are talking here about your internal versioning. Can you check the core ActivePivot version ? you can check that in the pom.xml dependencies for instance, assuming you have access to the server side code.